# Fill the Null values of the first row of dataframe with 100

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
51183 53423 51989 52483 51342
 100   NaN   NaN   83.33  NaN
 NaN   NaN   50     25    12.5
```

Here , '51183' , '53423'....are column names. I want to fill the null value present in the first row with 100.

I tried doing this:

```
df[:1].fillna(100)
```

It just changes the null values in the first row to 100 but it doesn't update it in the dataframe.

I want the result to look like this:

```
51183 53423 51989 52483 51342
 100   100   100   83.33  100
 NaN   NaN   50     25    12.5
```

If you could help me achieve that , I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `df.iloc[0]=df.iloc[0].fillna(100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the row, try this:

```py
df[:1] = df[:1].fillna(100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your try was almost OK.

`df[:1]` gets the initial row, but treats it as a **copy** of this row.

Then `.fillna(100)` changes all *NaN* values to *100*, but **in this copy**,
not in the table.

An attempt to add `inplace=True`:

```
df[:1].fillna(100, inplace=True)
```

does the job, but issues also a *SettingWithCopyWarning* warning.

A method to do the job without this warning is e.g. to use *.iloc* and then *.fillna*:

```
df.iloc[0].fillna(100, inplace=True)
```

Comment: definitely better than my answer